# How to schedule mail or any task as user set data and time in database

Tags: java, email, scheduled-tasks

I am developing spring boot application(server rest api), where users set alert date and time from front-end and data and time set in database. i want to send email to users as they set date and time in database. i have simple email in my git repo [Simple email in spring boot](https://github.com/ramandangol/SpringTestMail.git)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store the tasks persistently, you can use the Quartz scheduler. Other way is to use the `Timer`, but it will lose all the tasks on the process restart.

Comment: i have multi users and multi users set alert data and time as they need notification through email. is that possible and i'm just student i don't know how should i work for that can u help me sir to implement in my github repo spring_mail application.